# Creating model using mongoDb fails

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I started studying the MEAN stack a week back and was trying to create few sample web applications using it. I am facing a problem in my node.js when i am trying to create a model using the mongoDb with the below code:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mean-demo'); 
var employeeSchema=mongoose.Schema({name:String}); 
mongoose.model('employees',employeeSchema);
```

But I and error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

which points to `var employeeSchema=mongoose.Schema({name:String});`
I tried finding information regarding this on web but couldn't find a solution to it. Can someone please help?

Comment: Try `var Schema = mongoose.Schema; var employeeSchema = new Schema({name:String}); `

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. Now the error points to the second statement you mentioned above.

Comment: do you have the mongoose module installed? If so, do you have the mongoose object initialised anywhere like `var mongoose = require('mongoose');`?

Comment: Yes, i have instantiated it..

Comment: And are you still getting the same error? Your question does not show the relevant parts like the instantiation of the mongoose object.

Comment: I had not mentioned it while posting the comment. I have done this:

 mongoose=require('mongojs'),

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73360/discussion-between-anee-and-chridam).

Comment: That's not correct, it's supposed to be `mongoose=require('mongoose');` not `mongoose=require('mongojs');`